# Set Cross Domain in Codeigniter

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

When ever I run hosted project service run perfectly..

when i test with Other project that  give me error or i could not getting response from Services.
i try a lot but not working

**my Ajax Call:**

```
self.ValidLogin = function () {
         try {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/TEST/index.php/TestController/TestMethod?UserName=superadmin&Password=super",
                ,
                crossDomain: true,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                async: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                cache: false,
                success: function (response) {
                    alert("valid response");
                },
                error: function (ErrorResponse) {
                    alert("error");
                }

            });
        }
        catch (error) {
            alert("Catch:" + error);
        }
    }
```

**Service Side:**

```
public function TestMethod()
    {
        parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'],$_GET);
        $UserName = $_GET['UserName'];
        $Password = $_GET['Password'];

        $this->load->model('LoginModel');
        $result = $this->LoginModel->Login($UserName,$Password);

        header('Content-type: application/json');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
        echo json_encode($result);

    }
```

what should i do?

Comment: Do you have check your `get` success?

Comment: That always go in alert('Error')

Comment: Did you check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11599573/access-control-allow-origin-is-not-showing-up-in-response-headers-from-codeignit)?

Comment: Do u have any console error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After Long Rnd Got Solution

```
self.ValidLogin= function () {
        try {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/TEST/index.php/TestController/TestMethod?UserName=superadmin&Password=super",
                crossDomain: true,
                contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                async: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                processData: false,
                cache: false,
                success: function (response) {
                    alert("valid response");
                },
                error: function (ErrorResponse) {
                    alert("error");
                }
            });
        }
        catch (error) {
        }
    }
```

Comment: what's the difference?

Answer (score 3):

move

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*');
```

to the top

Comment: I have try but same result:(

Answer (score 2):

I have try this on my controller:

```
function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->output->set_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
}
```

And it work!
But no for all the pages. I still looking for a solution for all content.
I guess this config should be on autoload or something.