# Jquery ajax to another controller/method on codeigniter getting Cross origin issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Im using codeigniter to load a view. This view has a button to open a modal and in this modal i must load a method from another controller. To do this, i'm using ajax passing data by POST.

This is my ajax:

```
$('#modalView').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e){
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "../ci_visualizacao/comparaGrafico",
        crossDomain: true,
        data: { sensor: eqrel, ajax: "1" }
    }).done(function( data ) {
        $(".modal-body").html(data);
        $('.modal-body div:not(#chart)').hide();
    });
});
```

This view (comparaGrafico) has a javascript to initiate a highstock chart.

So the problem is that i'm getting this error when loading the ajax:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load javascript:;. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.
>
> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

The entire page loads but not the javascript part.

And it is in same origin! or not?
Is there another way to do this, or a solution to this problem?

thanks

Comment: change the usl, with `base_url()` and check once.

Comment: I'm running this in a .js file. I cant call base_url() but i can put the full url and the same happens.

Comment: add `index.php` in full url and check once.

Comment: I did. This is the full path: http://127.0.0.1/exehdager-teste/index.php/ci_visualizacao/comparaGrafico Same happens.

Comment: check this url. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25702991/enabling-cors-in-codeigniter-restserver-by-chriskacerguis, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20511988/set-cross-domain-in-codeigniter

Comment: Nothing from them.. Still the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

url should be

```
url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>ci_visualizacao/comparaGrafico"
```

### to use `base_url()`

In `config.php`

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
```

And in `autoload.php`

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

Comment: But I'm not in a php file. This is a js file.

Comment: I did. This is the full path: http://127.0.0.1/exehdager-teste/index.php/ci_visualizacao/comparaGrafico

Same happens.

Answer (score 0):

try adding this in constructor once.

```
public function __construct()
{
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
    parent::__construct();
}
```

Comment: On the destination controller or local?

Comment: destination controller.

Comment: add `contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",` in ajax

Comment: I did it too but no results. I'm still using those headers.

Comment: see this kink http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15602099/http-options-error-in-phil-sturgeons-codeigniter-restserver-and-backbone-js?rq=1, and add one more header

Comment: Sure! I even put on each controller and nothing changed