# avoiding CORS not working in codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, xmlhttprequest, cors

I am trying to work with AJAX request in my codeigniter app. 
At the end of my codeigniter controller function, I added

```
public somefunction(){

 $this->output->set_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
 $this->output->set_header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
 $this->output->set_content_type('application/json');
// plan contains array
 return $this->output->set_output(json_encode($plan));
}
```

`Normal get request works via server to server, but AJax calls shows the error.
XMLHttpRequest cannot load localhost:8888. Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.`

Here is the ajax calls

```
self.information = function() {
      $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: '',
          contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
      })
      .done(function(result) {
        console.log(result);
      })
      .fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
          alert(error);
      })
      .always(function(data){
      });
  }
```

The url works, since I checked it with postman and I get data returned. So no problem with that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20511988/set-cross-domain-in-codeigniter suggests changing the AJAX content type of the request. Maybe worth a try.

Comment: @apokryfos that was one of the first things I tried..

Comment: By the way is the `header(` part in the `set_header` really there or is it a copy/paste typo?

Comment: Though not CI related, [this answer talks about CORs and checking the headers from the server and what to send](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32501365/3585500).

Comment: @apokryfos OH yes that was  a typo before copying, I fixed it already.

Comment: @ourmandave taking a look

Comment: You need to set "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" headers in your response and include Content-Type to it.

Answer (score 3):

I came across the same issue today, what worked for me was defining the index_options method

```
public function index_options() {
    return $this->response(NULL, REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
}
```

and updating my the constructor to this

```
public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
}
```

Unfortunately I'm not familiar enough with access control to explain why this worked for me. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello Awad, so do I add it to my somefunction() ??? How does the whole thing work together?

Comment: @Farhana just define the index_options function just like your somefunction function, that will stop the browser from complaining about the preflight OPTIONS request. Next, move the header modifications to the constructor

Comment: the index_options function is not called anyhow, how will it load? Or the ci automatically loads it ?

Comment: Yes, if I'm not mistaken its the browser that calls the index_options function

Comment: @AwadMaharoof Saved the day!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to you to use [RestServer](https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver) for REST API which has CORS managing in it's settings.
Just set some settings in rest.php file in application/config folder:

```
$config['check_cors'] = true; //Set to TRUE to enable Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS).
$config['allowed_cors_headers'] = ['Header1','Header2'...] //If using CORS checks, set the allowable headers here
$config['allowed_cors_methods'] = ['GET','POST','OPTIONS',...] //If using CORS checks, you can set the methods you want to be allowed
$config['allow_any_cors_domain'] = true; //Set to TRUE to enable Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) from any source domain
$config['allowed_cors_origins'] = []; //specify what origins is allowed ($config['allow_any_cors_domain'] must be false)
```