# Cross domain request using angularJS

Tags: angularjs

I would like to display data from API using angularJS. This code works fine when run code on same PC. But when I tried to test on another PC then it is displaying error no **access-control-allow-origin' header is present on the requested resource. angularjs**

I am using 1.4.8

Here is my code :

```
$http({
            method:"get",
            url: 'http://IP/Test_API/index.php/test123_api/empdtl_from_empid/emp_id/'+$scope.empId
        })
        .success( function( response ){
            if (response != null || response != 'undefined') {
                $scope.empNm = response.data.emp_name;
            }
        })
        .error( function( response ) {
            if(response.statusCode == 404)
            {
                $scope.errorEmpNm = "You May Inputted Wrong Employee Id which have not Exist, Please Enter Correct Employee Id...!!!";
            }
        })
```

Comment: The problem is not in the angular code, but in the server API, what language are you using?

Comment: Seems duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18053547/angularjs-failed-to-load-resource-origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control/18053622#18053622

Comment: PHP with codeigniter REST API

Comment: maybe its help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11599573/access-control-allow-origin-is-not-showing-up-in-response-headers-from-codeignit

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS: No "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header is present on the requested resource](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29547003/angularjs-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-r)

Answer (score 3):

You can't solve it through javascript. The server you are making the request to has to implement CORS to grant `JavaScript` from your website access. Your `JavaScript` can't grant itself permission to access another website.

Answer (score 3):

You can try `$http.jsonp()`, it can make cross-origin requests, but the only option of request method is **GET**, and you can't use it to carry large payload because the browser may restrict URL length.

### Example

Pay attention to the **`callback=JSON_CALLBACK`** in the url!

```
var url = "http://other.domain.com/some/path?callback=JSON_CALLBACK";
$http.jsonp(url, {params: {param1: value1, param2: value2}})
     .success(function(response) {
       // ...
     })
     .error(function(response) {
       // ...
     })
```

Comment: I have tried Jsonp but it is not working for me can you please provide me example ?

Comment: @Hkachhia Example provided.

Comment: @Thanks: Is it use same syntax for post data ?

Comment: @Hkachhia As I said, you can't use jsonp to send POST requests, or any kind of requests other than **GET**.

Comment: Oh sorry. But how to POST data in cross domain ? you know that then help me

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable CORS on your response. A workaround is to use the enable [CORS plugin for Chrome](http://tps://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en) However, be aware that this is not a solution for real customers and it will have side effects on your browser. Only use it for testing.

The real fix is something that you have to do on the server side.  The way of enabling Allow-Control-Allow-Origin on your backend depends on the architecture of your backend. Add 'Allow-Control-Allow-Origin' to the header of your response and the problem will be fixed.

For PHP add the following to your response header

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```